# Hide a DIV element with two a password

Tags: javascript, onclick

**Hide a  DIV element with two a password**

I am a newbie and need to use multiple passwords. How to use multiple passwords

I don't know how to change.

```css
#HIDDENDIV {
    display: none;
}

#table td {
    padding: 1em;
    border: 1px solid black;
}


#table.show tr > *:nth-child(2) {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="passw">
            <div>
                (THE PASSWORD IS PASSWORD) <br />
                Enter the password to proceed:
            </div>
            <div>
            
                <input type="password" id="password" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('button').click()" /> <!-- IMPORTANT! this part is so if you click enter, it works. -->
                </div>
            

            <div>
                <br/>
                <input id="button" type="button" value="Login" onclick="if (document.getElementById('password').value == 'PASSWORD') { 
document.getElementById('table').classList.toggle('show');   document.getElementById('passw').style.display='none'; } 
else {  alert('Invalid Password!'); password.setSelectionRange(0, password.value.length);   } " />
            </div>
<!-- it will autoselect wrong input if wrong -->
    <br /><br /><br />
        </div>

<table id="table">
    <tr> 
        <td>stuff</td>
        <td id="HIDDENDIV" >hidden stuff</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
//for multiple password
var passowrdField = document.getElementById('password').value;


function passsword(){
   if (passowrdField == 'PASSWORD'|| passowrdField == 'Arindam' || passowrdField == 'Suman') { 
document.getElementById('table').classList.toggle('show');   document.getElementById('passw').style.display='none'; } 
else {  alert('Invalid Password!'); password.setSelectionRange(0, password.value.length);   } 
}
```

```css
#HIDDENDIV {
    display: none;
}

#table td {
    padding: 1em;
    border: 1px solid black;
}


#table.show tr > *:nth-child(2) {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="passw">
            <div>
                (THE PASSWORD IS PASSWORD) <br />
                Enter the password to proceed:
            </div>
            <div>
            
                <input type="password" id="password" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('button').click()" /> <!-- IMPORTANT! this part is so if you click enter, it works. -->
                </div>
            

            <div>
                <br/>
                <input id="button" type="button" value="Login" onclick="passsword()" />
            </div>
<!-- it will autoselect wrong input if wrong -->
    <br /><br /><br />
        </div>

<table id="table">
    <tr> 
        <td>stuff</td>
        <td id="HIDDENDIV" >hidden stuff</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You can use multiple password by using `||` operator plese check `or` operator from w3schools